# How can i change the non-radtabitems background color of a radtabcontrol?

Tags: wpf, telerik

i have a radtabcontrol with 2 radtabitems all of this controls have a #EEEEE color background but the issue is that the rest of the radtabcontrol have a different color
[image] as you can see in the image i marked with a black line the difference i was referring, how can i change that color?

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem, i have to change the color of the radtabcontrol HeaderBackground property